# Conflict with glossaries package and babel package

Tags: glossaries, babel

When I try to create a glossary and load babel package simultaneously the document will not compile correctly. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{example}{name={example},
description={example}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

Without the babel package the code works fine and a glossary is created.

The LOG file reads (sorry for the long text, but I can't figure what is important in it):

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.11.16) 30 DEC 2017 12:57
entering extended mode
**./main.tex
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2017/11/03 3.15 The Babel package
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def"
File: switch.def 2017/11/03 3.15 Babel switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
babel
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf"
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2017/11/03 3.15 Babel common definitions
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def"
File: switch.def 2017/11/03 3.15 Babel switching mechanism
)
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base\glossaries.sty"
Package: glossaries 2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mfirstuc\mfirstuc.sty"
Package: mfirstuc 2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
\@glsmfirst=\toks16
\@glsmrest=\toks17
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty"
Package: textcase 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xfor\xfor.sty"
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\datatool\datatool-base.sty"
Package: datatool-base 2017/11/12 v2.29 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen104
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count91
\leftroot@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count93
\DOTSCASE@=\count94
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count95
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count96
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count97
\dspbrk@lvl=\count98
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count99
\column@=\count100
\maxfields@=\count101
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\substr\substr.sty"
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\datatool\datatool-fp.sty"
Package: datatool-fp 2017/11/12 v2.29 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp.sty"
Package: fp 1995/04/02
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\defpattern.sty"
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count103
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-basic.sty"
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count104
\FP@xia=\count105
\FP@xib=\count106
\FP@xfa=\count107
\FP@xfb=\count108
\FP@rega=\count109
\FP@regb=\count110
\FP@regs=\count111
\FP@times=\count112
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-addons.sty"
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-snap.sty"
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-exp.sty"
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-trigo.sty"
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-pas.sty"
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-random.sty"
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count113
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-eqn.sty"
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-upn.sty"
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-eval.sty"
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks23
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count114
\dtl@tmplength=\skip46
\dtl@sortresult=\count115
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count116
\@dtl@datatype=\count117
\dtl@codeA=\count118
\dtl@codeB=\count119
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count120
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base\glossaries-compatible-3
07.sty"
Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2017/11/14 v4.35 (NLCT)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tracklang\tracklang.sty"
Package: tracklang 2017/03/25 v1.3.4 (NLCT) Track Languages
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tracklang\tracklang.tex"))
```

Comment: For me your MWE works as expected. The glossary is created after running PDFLaTeX twice. What exactly do you mean by 'does not compile correctly'?

Comment: Thx for your quick response. For me, the program compiles a long time and does not produce a pdf file. I will post the LOG file.

Comment: Looks as it miktex would like to install a missing package but can't do it. Synchronize the package database in the package managers (user and admin, menu repositories). If the problem persists, compile once on a command line to get a better error message.

Comment: Synchronizing was the problem. After synchronizing in the package manager problem was solved. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as it miktex would like to install a missing package but can't do it.

Synchronize the package database in the package managers (user and admin, menu repositories).

If the problem persists, compile once on a command line to get a better error message.